# Switching python path to Anaconda 3.6 on Mac OS X

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, path, anaconda

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed (with Anaconda), and have been using 3.6 regularly for months. But today I noticed my system was suddenly defaulting back to 2.7; I realized this when some of my normally used modules were not found, and confirmed with `python --version`. I think this happened because yesterday I tried running an IRAF installation script, and now I think that part of that script may have enforced Python 2. Now, there's a line in my `.bashrc` script that says:

```
export PATH=$HOME/research/local/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/research/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and below that, there are some lines to run an IRAF setup script (.sh script), but I'm not sure what that does.

I tried reassigning my python path by doing this in the terminal:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/anaconda3/bin/python"
source .bashrc
```

Because when I used to type `which python` that's the directory it would return. But no luck - now I keep getting `/Users/<myusername>/research/local/bin/python` in response. I also tried commenting out those export lines in `.bashrc` directly. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: When you type echo $PATH, do you still see $HOME/research/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages? You probably need to remove this from your path.

Comment: Python 3 should actually always called as `python3`, while Python 2 uses `python` as the name of the executable. Can you check that you are calling the right one`